# Gamma Function Integral Identity

Tags: complex-analysis, analytic-number-theory, gamma-function, l-functions

On p.11 of D. Bump's "Automorphic Forms and Representations" he uses the following identity in a proof of the functional equation of a Dirichlet $L$-function:

$$ \int_0^\infty e^{-\pi tn^2}t^{(s+\varepsilon)/2} \frac{dt}{t} = \pi^{-(s+\varepsilon)/2} \Gamma\left(\frac{s+\varepsilon}{2}\right)n^{-s-\varepsilon}$$

where $\Re(s) > 1$ and $\varepsilon \in \{0, 1\}$.

The only thing I know about the Gamma function is its definition via the integral

$$\Gamma(s) = \int_0^\infty x^{s-1}e^{-x}dx.$$

How do I prove the identity Bump cites?

Comment: $$\Gamma \left( \frac{1}{2} \right ) = \sqrt{\pi}$$ is of any help?

Comment: Thanks for the hint, but I haven't managed to use it. I don't know how to handle the exponent of $e$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A change of variable should work
\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty e^{-\pi tn^2}t^{(s+\varepsilon)/2-1} dt &=_{u=\pi n^2t} \int_0^\infty e^{-u}\left(\frac{u}{\pi n^2}\right)^{(s+\varepsilon)/2-1}\frac{du}{\pi n^2} \\
=& \pi^{-(s+\varepsilon)/2} \Gamma\left(\frac{s+\varepsilon}{2}\right)n^{-s-\varepsilon}
\end{align}